# Getting Active Directory Users and looping through them to return a new list using F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have tried several ways to get this to work, I am thinking I need to some kind of recursive function but haven't been able to wrap my head around it. Looked at folds and catamorphism and don't really get how I could apply it this this situation. I also, tried an example with yeild.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
//Function: Get AD User Directory Services
let getADUserDS (searchBase:string,filter:string) =
    let dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+searchBase)
    let propertiesToLoad = [|"samaccountname"|]
    let dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry,filter,propertiesToLoad)
    let searchResults = dSearcher.FindAll()
    let results: String List = []
    //let newSearchResults = [for u in searchResults do let r = u.GetDirectoryEntry() && let a: String List = [r.Properties.["samaccountname"].Value.ToString()] && yeild a]
    //let results = newSearchResults |> List.filter ((<>) "")
    for u in searchResults do
        match u with
            | null -> printfn ""
            | u when u.ToString() = ""-> printfn ""
            | _ ->  let r = u.GetDirectoryEntry()
                    let a: String List = [r.Properties.["samaccountname"].Value.ToString()]
                    results |> List.append <| a |> ignore

    results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an Active Directory available, so I was not able to test this. However, one line in your code that is definitely not right is the following one:

```
results |> List.append <| a |> ignore
```

I suppose you are trying to add the new value `a` to the list of `results`, but F# lists are immutable, so this just creates a new list and then ignores it using `ignore`.

Using list comprehensions as you attempted in the commented-out version is defintely one good way of going about this. The correct syntax incluing your `match` code would be:

```
let newSearchResults = 
  [ for u in searchResults do
      match u with
      | null -> printfn ""
      | u when u.ToString() = ""-> printfn ""
      | _ ->  let r = u.GetDirectoryEntry()
              yield r.Properties.["samaccountname"].Value.ToString() ]
```

Alternatively, you can use functions like `List.map` and `List.filter`. One caveat is that `dSearcher.FindAll` is not returning a generic `IEnumerabl` and so you need some extra work to turn this result into a normal F# list - a simple list comprehension can do this nicely for you:

```
let searchResults = [ for r in dSearcher.FindAll() -> r ]
let newSearchResults = 
  searchResults 
  |> List.filter (fun u -> u <> null && u.ToString() <> "")
  |> List.map (fun u ->
      let r = u.GetDirectoryEntry()
      r.Properties.["samaccountname"].Value.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, Both methods worked perfectly! I actually have some other places that this will help as well. I did have another question...The first method seems much easier to read, is there a benefit that the second method would have over the first?